# Redirect users to mobile site with htaccess when I have two sites hosted under one account?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile, sites

I have a website and a mobile website (the mobile website is a subdomain where the files are in a subfolder). I have used an htaccess file to redirect mobile users to the mobile site where they can also go back to the full site. This worked great until I added a second website within a subfolder so I would only have one hosting account. Because my htaccess file is in the root folder of the main site, mobile users are redirected to the mobile version of the first site before they ever even reach the second site. Is there a better way to do this or do I need to just purchase two hosting accounts?

I don't have a mobile version of the second site yet, but would like one in the future. I use godaddy to host the sites.

Comment: Should be possible, you just have to modify the rewriterules to match certain domains only. Something like `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$`

Comment: I have very little knowledge with htaccess and even got the code I have from someone else. Is there somewhere I can learn more about it?

Answer (score 0):

Work around I found was to take the same htaccess file and put it in each domain root folder then edit it to redirect to itself.  It works for me.  But I agree, all of the htaccess rewrites that I have seen all have the same effect......redirecting to the first mobile site.  I wish someone could solve this.